# how to print just filename without using __FILE__ in C

Tags: c, linux

I want to print the filename that is being used in my project.
But if I use `__FILE__`, it prints entire path along with the file name which is long in my case and disturbs the log indents.

Can anyone please help how I can print just the file name using a common parameter across my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your C code, you might use instead of `__FILE__` the expression `basename(__FILE__)`; however, this has the disadvantage of calling `basename` at every occurrence.

Alternatively, compile `path/foo.c`  with a command like

```
gcc -Wall -c -g -DBASE_FILE=\"foo\" path/foo.c
```

(you could have a generic `make` rule giving that : with [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) use [functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) like `basename` and [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) )

then use `BASE_FILE` instead of `__FILE__` in your code.

With GCC, you could use [`__BASE_FILE__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html) instead of `__FILE__`

Comment: +1 for the useful macros.

Comment: Unfortunately this approach is not good because it will not report header names properly, you'll get a line number referencing some header but still get the cpp filename.

Comment: __BASE_FILE__ gave me the same full path as __FILE__ when I tried it today.  I didn't make any changes to my file other than add __BASE_FILE__, so maybe I did something wrong.  gcc 9.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [basename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html). I don't think the preprocessor gives you much more than `__FILE__`.